# Eigen, rotate a Vector3d with a quaternion, from a given point?

Tags: vector, eigen, quaternions

I have two 3d points, as `Eigen::Vector3d`.

I need to rotate the second point by a quaternion, *around the first point*'

I usually use this to rotate a Vector:

```
Eigen::Vector3d point; //point to rotate
Eigen::Quaterniond quat, p2; //quat to rotate by, temp

p2.w() = 0;
p2.vec() = point;
Eigen::Quaterniond rotatedP1 = quat * p2 * quat.inverse();
Eigen::Vector3d rotatedPoint = rotatedP1.vec();
```

This works, but it rotates the point around zero.

How can I rotate the point around another point?
As if the first point is rotating, and the second point is 'parented' to it.

In the image below, I am getting a rotation around the green axis, and i want it around the red axis, by passing `point2` into the function somehow.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To rotate a vector `point` around the origin by `quat`, you just write `quat * point` (because the `*` operator is overloaded accordingly).

To rotate around a different point, you need to shift the point then rotate and shift it back.

```
 quat * (point - point2) + point2
```

If `quat` and `point2` are known before you can also calculate

```
 quat * point + (point2 - quat * point2)
```

where the part in parentheses can be precalculated.

Comment: Thank you! (last comment deleted as I had a code typo). That works great.